# Are there any trigonometric functions that will generate no real answers?

Tags: trigonometry

I am creating a computer program that is a calculator. I know $x/0$ will not have a real answer, which got me thinking. I don't know trig, so I came here to find out if using $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $\tan(x)$, and, on a separate note, $\sqrt{x}$, are there any values of $x$ that won't return a real number?
Note: I know that any negative value of $x$ for sqrt will equal an imaginary number.
Edit: To clarify, $x$ is real.

Comment: $\tan\left(k\pi+\frac\pi2\right)$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$ is not defined.

Comment: If you handle inverse trig functions, the values of e.g. $\arcsin(x)$ or $\arccos(x)$ are complex for $|x| > 1$.

Comment: The language you're coding in may well know the answer to your question, and return some appropriate error status when the input is bad. Perhaps you can trap that and deal accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to know is the "domain" of these various functions.

If you are only dealing with real numbers, then the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is all non-negative reals (i.e. $x \geq 0$).

On the other hand, the domains of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ is all real numbers.

The domain of $\tan(x)$ is everywhere $x$ is not equal to $\pi/2$ plus an integer multiple of $\pi$. In particular, $x\not=\dots, -\dfrac{3\pi}{2},-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2},\dfrac{5\pi}{2},\dots$ (where $x$ is measure in radians). In degrees this would be $x \not= -270,-90,90,270,450,\dots$

As for the other trig functions, secant (i.e. $\sec(x)$) has the same domain as tangent.

Cosecant and cotangent (i.e. $\csc(x)$ and $\cot(x)$) have the domain of all reals not equal to an integer multiple of $\pi$ (measuring in radians). In particular, $x \not= \dots,-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi,\dots$ (or in degrees $x\not=\dots,-360,-180,0,180,360,540,\dots$).

Answer (score 1):

The functions sine and cosine return a real number for each real input. The tangent function will not return a real number if the input is $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ for some integer $k$, but it will return a real number otherwise.

Comment: Should be $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ (it was my mistake as well).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Edited. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the tangent function is undefined for input of $\pi/2 + 2k\pi$. This is because $\tan x \equiv \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and so it is undefined where $\cos x = 0 $.

In addition $\sin z \equiv \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $\cos z \equiv \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$. So if you allow complex input, then you can get complex output.